# Twitter Bootstrap model

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to make functioning bootstrap model, but it does not work.Not able to find what I am missing.
jsfiddle: [jsFiddle link here](http://jsfiddle.net/5za2a/9/)

```
<div id="modal-3" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">No</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
</div>
```

```
<a href="#modal-3" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Confirm</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `hide` class on the modal container. It is redundant with the modal itself. Working example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/GKURL/1/

`<div id="modal-3" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    ...`

Comment: Please have a look to my related problem...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20872959/show-twitter-bootstrap-model-on-form-submit

Answer (score 0):

You are missing, bootstrap.min.js or bootstrap modal.js , don't forget to initiate.

add `$('#myModal').modal();` or `$('#myModal').modal({ options });`
 at the bottom of your script.

[more about bootstrap modal APIs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Comment: bootstrap.min.js is added, As you can see it in external Resources.

Comment: Oops, didn't notice that. Then you haven't initiliazed

Comment: I had tried $('#myModal').modal() as well, but model does not shown